# Why does my "old-style" function print 2 when passed a float?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I wrote some C code for a quiz. The question is, what does this program print according to the C17 standard:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(a)
{
    auto b = 1.7f;
    printf("%d\n", (int) (a + b));
}

int main(void)
{
    foo(10.6f);
}
```

I expected the answer to be `11`. My reasoning is this: `a` defaults to `int` because that's what happens if you don't specify a type for a parameter (in < C23), so `10.6f` gets type cast into an `int` with the value `10`. `b` defaults to `int` because `auto` simply means automatic storage duration (again, in < C23), so `1.7f` gets type cast into an int with the value `1`.

However, the function prints `2`, seemingly regardless of the value of the float that's passed into the function. If I instead pass an int, it works like I would expect.

What's going on here? What am I misunderstanding?

**edit**: I'm starting to suspect UB. Because if I do this:

```
float f = 10.6f;
printf("%f\n", f);
foo(f);
```

I get `1` as the result.

Comment: Clang says that *"C99 and later do not support implicit int"* so I guess what you just wrote is invalid C17.

Comment: "I'm starting to suspect UB" - most definitely smells like it.

Comment: _Because if I do this… I get `1` as the result_ Feels like an ABI issue?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Ok, well that makes sense. Although, if I compile with `-std=c89` I still get the same behavior, just no warnings.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/qM9vPK95o

Comment: @mortelsson oh I see, now that is interesting.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I forgot to say that I'm compiling with GCC. Clang seems to produce the output I expect.

Comment: Yes, calling a function other than with the correct argument types (`int`, in this case) is definitely undefined behaviour.  Printing `2` is just as appropriate as phoning your boss to say you've resigned, as far as C is concerned.

Comment: @TobySpeight But only in the case where I don't explicitly provide types for the parameters? If I have a function that explicitly takes an int, i would expect an implicit conversion to int if I pass it a float. Are you saying the following are not equivalent: `void foo(a)`, and `void foo(int a)`?

Comment: @mortelsson: Does the observed behavior change if you change the code from `void foo(a)` to `void foo(int a)` ?  If it changes, it proves they are not equivalent (the inverse is not true, however)

Comment: Correct, @mortelsson.  The requirement that (default-argument-promoted) argument types be compatible with function parameter types applies only to functions declared without a prototype.  For functions declared with a prototype, the requirement is instead that (actual) argument types be implicity convertable to the declared parameter type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The question is, what does this program print according to the C17 standard:

The correct answer is: ***C17 does not specify what the output of the program should be.***

There are two related issues with this function ...

> ```
> void foo(a)
> {
>     auto b = 1.7f;
>     printf("%d\n", (int) (a + b));
> }
> ```

**The type of parameter `a` is not specified.**  In C17, it is allowed to specify that type either along with its identifier, ANSI-style ...

```
void foo(float a)
```

... or in a separate declaration list, K&R style ...

```
void foo(a)
double a;
```

.  It is *not* permitted to omit it altogether (C17 6.7/7, 6.9.1/6).

**The type of local variable `b` is not specified.**  In C17 and earlier, `auto` specifies only automatic storage duration, which is the default for block-scope variables anyway.  It has no implications for data type, and C17 requires all object definitions to specify a data type explicitly (C17 6.7/7).

For each of those reasons, independently, the behavior of the program is undefined.

Among the various versions of ISO C, only C90 has implicit data typing. That would resolve the above issues by defaulting the types of `a` and `b` to `int`, but in this case the call `foo(10.6f)` has undefined behavior on account of the the type of the argument, as adjusted by the default argument promotions, not being compatible with the type of the function parameter.

Thus, in fact, *no* version of C says what the output of the program should be.

> If I instead pass an int, it works like I would expect.

If the argument is an `int` then the program behavior is defined by C90, and some compilers that default to newer versions of C will still accept it for backwards compatibility.

> What's going on here?

Undefined behavior all over the place.

Answer (score 6):

It is undefined behaviour :

6.5.2.2 - 6

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
> does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on
> each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to
> double. These are called the default argument promotions. If the
> number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the
> behavior is undefined. If the function is defined with a type that
> includes a prototype, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis
> (, ...) or the types of the arguments after promotion are not
> compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is
> undefined.

`float` is promoted to `double` and then you call the function which requires `int`

Comment: Well, that explains it clearly.

Comment: That would be the answer in C90.  In C17, on the other hand, it is not true that the OP is calling a function that requires an `int`.  The problem there (or one of them) is that function `foo`'s parameter type is not defined in the first place.  Or more directly that the (empty) declaration list for K&R-style `foo()` does not contain an entry for parameter `a`.